# Facing issue of 'Stack Corruption' on function return

Tags: c++, pointers

I get the error as `"stack corruption detected : aborted"` randomly on a function return. My code is as below:

```
struct SND_RCV_CMD_t
{
    int    nRspFieldsCnt;
    char** rspValues;
}

void SendAndReceive(SND_RCV_CMD_t *cmdParams)
{
    cmdParams->rspValues = SendAndReceiveEx(&cmdParams->nRspFieldsCnt);
}

char** SendAndReceiveEx(int* resFieldsCnt)
{
    char** retFields = 0;
    *resFieldsCnt = 0;
    int maxStrings = 500;

    retFields = (char**)malloc(maxStrings * sizeof(char*));

    for(int id = 0; id < maxStrings; id++)
    {
        retFields[id] = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
        memset(retFields[id], 0x00, 30);
        sprintf(retFields[id], "%s", fieldVal);
    }

    return retFields;  //At this point I got stack corruption error
}
```

When I call `SendAndReceive` method my code crashes sometime at the end of `SendAndReceiveEx` method. And error says `"Stack corruption detected : aborted"`.

Comment: any stacktrace?... if so add that into your question

Comment: unfortunatly, android logcat does not show more than stack corruption message.

Comment: What do you know about the length of the contents of `fieldVal`? Could that be longer than 30 characters? Best insert an explicit `if` to check this, and don't carry out the `sprintf` if it the string is too long.

Comment: No, fieldVal will be of 14 character max

Comment: does it crash on the first call of the method or is it only after many calls? where does `SendAndReceive` is called?

Comment: It's unlikely the issue, but what are you doing the memset for?

Comment: @Frederik.L It does not crash on first dew call. It crshes after 4 to 5 call to SendAndReceive Method.

Comment: @kibibu I thought I am dealing with char*, so better add null. but though it crashing.

Comment: Thinking about the fact that you allocate 30 `char` for a string of length no more than 14 characters: Is this because you are dealing with non-Latin characters and expect up to 2 `char` units per character, or something like that? Just in case: You may very well have 3 or more `char` units for one character in many encodings (most notably, in UTF-8).

Comment: @jogojapan ya, something like that. the receive string can be in any format. I need to test your last statement too. 3 char per unit.

Comment: @sam18 3 or more... If you are dealing with anything that isn't plain ASCII, you need to be really careful about how count characters vs. `char`.

Comment: I think that a good way to know if it's an overflow could be to try calling it with a constant that fits in. If it passes flawlessly for let's say 100 times, then we can highly suppose that it's value dependent; if it still crashes, troubles are more likely at memory management level.

Comment: Guys I found the reason and its the same you all mentioned. `fieldVal` was the culprit. sometimes while updating `fieldVal` it gets crashed. So, now I need to track down that variable. Thanks you all. I need to mark someone as answer. So I have picked one. but lot of people gives the correct direction. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can see in your code that might be hiding this kind of error would be if `fieldVal` is overflowing the buffer you've allocated.

You could check the return value of `sprintf` to see how many char's it's writing.

Have you tried something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)?

Comment: Other people doubting the same fieldVal variable. I think I need to recheck again.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `snprintf`. If `fieldVal` is exactly 30 or bigger, then it can corrupt your memory.

Another thing is that `resFieldsCnt` is set to 0. Is this correct? because you don't change the value afterwards, so why pass it in?

Comment: Yeah, I think it can be helpful. Let me give it a try.